# Metadata for closed captioned subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

I have a video file (`mp4.mp4`) and two subtitle files (`cc.srt` and `sub.srt`).

Both subtitle files are in English but the first one has sound effects "[gasps]" and "[coughs]".

If I add them with this command:

```
$ ffmpeg                               \
    -i mp4.mp4 -i cc.srt -i sub.srt    \
    -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1 -map 2    \
    -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text  \
    -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng       \
    -metadata:s:s:1 language=eng       \
out.mp4
```

But these are hard to tell apart in players since they both show up as just "English".

How can I add metadata so that the first shows up as "English (CC)" (or something more appropriate)?

Comment: idk how to do this in ffmpeg, but the one with [gasps] etc is known as an SDH subtitle track [Subtitles for the deaf and hearing impaired]. It should be tagged English (SDH) to differentiate.

Comment: -metadata:s:s:0 title=Full -metadata:s:s:1 title=SDH